# Create Structured Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

lets assume i have this (snippet):

```
var filesarray = [];
            if(req.files){
                req.files.forEach(function(file){
                    var fileName = file.filename;
                    var filePath = file.path;
                    filesarray.push(
                            filePath
                    );
        })
}
```

And later i push it with mongoose:

```
DB.create({
              filepaths: filesarray,
              }), function (err, res) {
              if (err)  {
                throw err;
              }else{
                console.log("1 document inserted");
                DB.close()
            }}          
    });
```

The result i receive is not really what i want, because in mongodb i get a comma separated list, like:

```
filepaths
/files/1540474914824.png,/files/1540474914828.png,files/1540474914831.png
```

I would like to have something like:

```
filepaths
       filename -> filepath
       filename -> filepath
       filename -> filepath
```

i hope i could make clear whats the goal. I am sure there is a elegant way to reacht the goal, so could someone please give me a direction.

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you cant have more than one key in am object so `{filepaths: {file: '1', file: '2'}}` will not work. You will need to have a unique name per file/path

```
var files = {};
    if(req.files){
        req.files.forEach(function(file){
            var fileName = file.filename;
            var filePath = file.path;
            files[fileName] = filePath;
        })
    }
```

you could use `map` to have an array of object but this seems more cumbersome to me

```
var files;
    if(req.files){
        files = req.files.map(function(file){
            var fileName = file.filename;
            var filePath = file.path;
            return { [fileName]: filePath };
        })
    }
```